# How to document prototype functions in IIFEs in VS2015 with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, prototype, intellisense, jsdoc

Recently my team (finally) upgraded to VS2015 and I noticed one of the new features is JSDoc support for customizing intellisense and documentation of javascript functions/objects. I started trying to implement it and wasted a couple hours trying to get prototype functions to get "intellisensed" correctly.

I noticed that the @typedef tag works when the constructor function and its prototype functions aren't written in an IIFE.

[image]

Notice, the function protoFunction appears and its @param tag also works...

But, if I wrap the same code in an IIFE, functions disappears from the intellisense menu.

[image]

Here, the @property tag still works for the "a" property but the protoFunction is missing completely. I tried this same code in WebStorm and it works perfectly. Is this just a bug in VS2015 or am I specifying these JSDoc tags incorrectly?

Edit: To address Matt McMahon's comment, the scope closed in the IIFE shouldn't affect the documentation of the objects I'm creating. Regardless of whether or not I can access the TestObj object, if I use JSDoc to declare a function whose first parameter is of type "{TestObj}" then the intellisense should treat it as such.

This is how it works in other IDEs. Here's a screenshot of the same code in WebStorm where the protoFunction remains in the intellisense menu:

[image]

Edit 2: I've restructured the code to expose the object from the IIFE and also avoided adding the function to the prototype and instead using Object.create, but the issue still happens. Note in the following image I can still see the "a" property I specified in the JSDoc in the intellisense window, but not the protoFunction that I added. Additionally, I can't see the "b" property that I omitted from the JSDoc tag, which shows that the "a" property in the intellisense IS coming from the JSDoc tag.

[image]

Comment: Given the code sample you provide, TestObj isn't reachable from outside of the IIFE -- so it shouldn't be in the intellisense menu.

Comment: It's a contrived example showing the problem, but even if I did expose it, it won't work. The JSDoc tags should just document the structure and not care about whether or not I can actually get it.

Additionally, the second image shows that it still works anyway, just lacks the function. I can still see the "String a" in intellisense. Also, again, this works perfectly in the WeStorm IDE.

Comment: I'll add that while scope doesn't allow it, by specifying the type of the parameter in the JSDoc tag, the intellisense treats it as if the variable is that type.. It's just missing the functions that were added to the prototype.

Comment: Just out of curiosity have you tried exposing your object from the IIFE. I understand you comment about it only documenting but in the real world you would be exposing it if you wish to use it outside. Even more interesting i wonder how it behaves when you abandon `new` in favor of `Object.Create`, no longer access `.prototype` and use factories instead, but i digress.

Comment: Yes, I've tried exposing the object and it doesn't affect the intellisense. Additionally, the function SomeFunction should be callable from within the IIFE anyway and so should have proper intellisense if I'm referencing a TestObj.

Again, the intellisense works just fine for everything except for functions added to the prototype. Please refer to my 2nd edit in the question. I've added an image showing how exposing the object doesn't affect this issue.